# Dimension too large in pgf plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dimensions

I am trying to create a pgf plot which includes (among others) a constant function f(x)=1. My x-axis should be restricted to some range (see below), and there is also a restriction on the y-axis. This is the minimal code that reproduces the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=.1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2]
    \addplot {1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code produces the error

```
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)         <7> on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)         <5> on input line 11.
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgf@xx

l.11           \end{axis}

I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
! Dimension too large.
```

The last seven lines of the error message repeat 5 times. This happens no matter what values I use for the `ymin` and `ymax` parameters, but only for certain `xmin` and `xmax`. From trying different values, my guess would be that `xmin`-`xmax` has to be greater than approximately 0.15 for LaTeX to compile this successfully, but in my use case it has to be a range from `xmin=.0005` to `xmax=.0027`.

Why does LaTeX throw an error when the range is too small (or is there something else wrong with my code)?

```
~ $ pdflatex -version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) that you are plotting an expression, and give it a `domain`:

```
 \addplot expression[domain=0:1]{1};
```

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=.1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=2]
    \addplot expression[domain=0:1]{1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem for me. I had to use the values `0:0.01` because of the x values I was using. Is there a reason why LaTeX can draw this expression without being told a domain if the difference of the values of `xmin` and `xmax` is large enough, but fails otherwise?

Comment: According to the manual, `expression` is implied in the absence of any other input type.

Comment: @PaulGessler indeed, but compare the output from `\addplot [domain=0:1]{1};` and `\addplot expression[domain=0:1]{1};`

Comment: Interesting---the difference I see is that the style `black` is applied in the case where `expression` is left out. Is this documented?